# I'm trying to delete a row using an array. Can you tell me the grammar of orm?

Tags: arrays, django

I'm trying to delete a row using an array.
Can you tell me the grammar of orm?

```
def todo_delete_ajax(request):

    todo_ids = request.POST.getlist('todo_arr[]')
    # result : todo_ids :  ['76', 97]

    if todo_ids:
        print("todo_ids : ", todo_ids)
        return redirect('/todo/')
    else:
        print("todo_ids : ", todo_ids)

    return redirect('/todo/')
```

I want to use Django orm and delete 76,97 of todo model

Thank you if you let me know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Todo.objects.filter(pk__in=todo_ids).delete()
```

But the above is not very safe:

1. you do not verify that the AJAX request is performed by a logged in user; and
2. that the user has access to these `Todo` objects, for example if he/she is the owner.

This thus means that a hacker can "inject" primary keys of other users their `Todo` objects.

In case the `Todo` model has an `owner` field, you can prevent that with:

```
@login_required
def todo_delete_ajax(request):
    todo_ids = request.POST.getlist('todo_arr[]')
    if todo_ids:
        Todo.objects.filter(pk__in=todo_ids, owner=request.user).delete()
    return redirect('/todo/')
```

You probably also want to use the name of the view in the `redirect` call, so:

```
@login_required
def todo_delete_ajax(request):
    todo_ids = request.POST.getlist('todo_arr[]')
    if todo_ids:
        Todo.objects.filter(pk__in=todo_ids, owner=request.user).delete()
    return redirect('name-of-todo-view')
```

since by using a hardcoded URL, if you change the path of that URL, or you run your server under a specific path, then the URL will turn invalid.

Comment: I think it will help a lot. Thanks for the detailed answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks to the way you told me, the problem was solved. Good day. Thank you